# EF Code first and Database first

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I'm going to start an new application with MVC Web API. Api should communicate with DB. Data base is not yet designed, but this DB will communicate with more then one application. So which way I have to choose.

Comment: Code first will be a good approach. With code first you can even track your database changes using your source control. You may will that you have to write more mode. But at the same time you will get more control over it.

Comment: Database first won't work the same way in EF Core. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890367.aspx

Comment: Think how you are going to manage database changes etc. Are you going to use EF migrations or have a DBA control the changes. Also, how you are going to keep all your applications up to date. Finally, how you are going to roll new versions of applications and database in production so that nothing breaks (not strictly CodeFirst/DbFirst question but still worth thinking about). Working with EF migrations in larger team has some issues. If you do DbFirst with edmx/csdl/ssdl/msl merges to these files can be the issue. Also if you customize model (csdl) updates db you will overwrite your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code first is a good chooice for you, for the following reasons:

- Code first is prefered by programmers
- Good support in EF Core
- more flexibility
- You can use bounded context to communicate with other databases

Other info:

The image is copyied from:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/choosing-development-approach-with-entity-framework.aspx

[image: decision tree which apporach]